# Set input value with a String which comes from a java class

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, hsqldb

I have an input field in which the user enters an ID. Now i want, that the product name will be shown in a seperat input field next to the old one.

```
<input type="text" name="productName" id="productName" disabled>
```

My JavaScript test:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function setProductName() {

<%
int a = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("pName"));
String test = Projektarbeit.getProductName(a);

    document.getElementById('productName').value = <%=test%>;
}

</script>
```

And last but not least my method, which gets the Product Name, this method is in a seperat Java class!

```
public static String getProductName(int ID) {
    String x = "";

    try {
        stmt = DBTools.getConnection().createStatement();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT NAME FROM PRODUCT WHERE ID = ' " + ID + "';");

        while (rs.next()) {
            x = rs.getString("Name");
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e);
    }

    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not fix all your problems, but your attempt to print out a value from JSP scriptlet into Javascript was failing due to not properly opening and closing the scriptlet tags. Also, you need to wrap quotes around that printing of the `test` variable since it is a string (otherwise you end up with a syntax error in the resultant Javascript):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setProductName() 
{
   <%
   int a = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("pName"));
   String test = Projektarbeit.getProductName(a);
   %>
  document.getElementById('productName').value = "<%=test%>";
}
</script>
```

Of course in reality, you need to understand something more about this approach.  When you call the Javascript function `setProductName()` it is NOT going to re-execute this JSP code.  This JSP code will be executed once, on page call, and then print into the Javascript for that page a hardcoded value for `test`.  Every subsequent call to the Javascript function `setProductName()` will merely set the element's value to the hardcoded `test` value (until refresh of the page picks up a different value).  If you want calls to `setProductName()` to execute server-side code and retrieve a new value each time, you will need to learn Ajax. But since this is based on the numeric value of `request.getParameter("pName")` maybe that is not a concern here.